# Need help/info with my case for PR (Australia)

Tags: australia, indian-citizens, pr

I will try to keep it as short as possible as I value your time.

- I am from India, 27 years of age. I did my Bachelors (B-Tech) in Electronics & Telecommunication in 2013.
- But my skills and work experience (Self Employed) is not related to my B-Tech.
- I am successfully running my own web-design company since 2014. My skill set is Webdesign, Web-development, Graphics, Branding & Animation. I learned all this on my own so I do not have any certifications/short courses as well.
- I am working with many clients & companies based in Australia. They are ready to help with anything if required for my PR application. I also have visited Australia twice, I got my visitor visa approved the last December.
- I am looking to apply for a subclass 189 Visa to get PR. Following is the list of occupations that are related to my skill set and not my study (B-Tech).

  1. 261211: Multimedia Specialist
  2. 261212: Web Developer
  3. 261312: Developer Programmer
  4. 261313: Software Engineer
  5. 232414: Web Designer
  6. 232411: Graphic Designer
- I will be able to get 30 points for Age, 20 points for English.
- The query is will I be able to get 15 points for my Bachelor degree as it's not related to the occupation I am applying visa for. Also what about points for my work experience as I am self-employed (running my own company since 2014)
- For Multimedia Specialist, the Occupation Ceiling Value is 1000 but invitations issued are 0, What does this mean? So should I not consider applying under this occupation?
- I just wanted to know what will be my best bet to apply for PR. I do not mind if my application takes time, I am in no rush and can wait for 1-2 years or more for PR.